# Can I make my own TFT LCD shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, shields, tft

I have a few TFT LCD displays lying around which I salvaged from old phones. I would really like to use them with my Arduino. I didn't get anything about making a shield on the net but only links to eBay and Amazon. Please help.[image: here is one TFT LCD]
It is a 36 pin tft for which adapters can be found.
But I don't know the wiring or the pins concerned.[image]
Here is the supposed pin data sheet for my lcd for ur help

Comment: gre_gor , the image I provided shows the commonest of LCDs with 36 pins, for which adapters can be found. The question you refer above has a lcd with a custom adapter, and thus of very limited use in a Arduino.Thanks though.

Comment: Well I asked about the wiring and the concerned pins to which I can connect it. I don't know about that. And I couldn't get the wiring diagram of the tft shield that is in the market.

Comment: The adapter is irrelevant. The answer is the same.

Comment: Thanks , but I will wait for some others to answer. No hard feelings though gre_gor.

Comment: Unless you can get the datasheet for the TFT with the details of each pin on the connector you have zero chance.

Comment: Majenko, I am adding a pic to my question that shows the pin data sheet for a 3.5 inch tft lcd, and I think mine should be similar. Please help now.

Comment: Unless it is the exact same screen by the exact same manufacturer chances are it's different. There is no standard, and many screens the "same size" are completely different.

Comment: TFT shields are so cheap why waste your time trying to salvage something you have no data for? If you want to make your own (and I make my own systems with built-in TFT screens) buy a new TFT screen that you can get the datasheet for. I get mine from http://www.buydisplay.com